# how to get the compiled extended to a function or loop

Tags: c++, performance, compiler-construction, build

I have a function with a loop that I would get the extended development of the loop in c++ code. Also I have a recursive function that I wanted to get the same.

An example of I need:

```
for (i = 0; i <4; i++)
{
      printf ("%d", "example");
}
```

should result that i need

```
printf ("%d", "example");
printf ("%d", "example");
printf ("%d", "example");
printf ("%d", "example");
```

this is a simple example. But I would need to do this for more complex functions.
For what it's worth I use `visual c++`.
I do not know if there is a build option for this.

Comment: Errr... `i + +`? `% d`? Really? I mean, I'm all in favour of whitespace...

Comment: Any decent compiler should unroll loops, if it makes sense for performance and optimizing is activated. But: prtintf ("% d", "example"); isnt valid at all - you probably wanted to write printf("%d", i); See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding#C_example

Comment: There's nothing wrong with trusting the compiler to optimise your code. It'll do a reasonable job, most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual C++ does not have an explicit option for loop unrolling. However, if you turn optimisations on, then the optimiser loop unrolls based on heuristic. Loop unrolling is a trade-off - it may or may not result in improved performance.

Here is a [discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/d0b225c2-f5b0-4bb9-ac6a-4d4f61f7cb17) on loop unrolling in Visual C++.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using GCC to compile your code, then you can use `-funroll-loop` option to unloop this loop.

The [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) says,

> - **-funroll-loops**
>     Unroll loops whose number of iterations can be determined at compile time or upon entry to the loop. -funroll-loops implies -frerun-cse-after-loop. This option makes code larger, and may or may not make it run faster.

There is another (similar) option:

> - **-funroll-all-loops**
>     Unroll all loops, even if their number of iterations is uncertain when the loop is entered. This usually makes programs run more slowly. -funroll-all-loops implies the same options as -funroll-loops,

Comment: You definitely deserve an up-vote, if only for managing to figure out that he was looking for loop unrolling.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Funnily enough, the word "development" has a meaning similar to "unrolling" in several languages when considered in a mathematical context...

Comment: Ah, that would help. I started to write a comment asking what "extended development of the loop" was supposed to mean, but then decided not to post it.